# What happened in asp.net 2.0 when session lost?

Tags: asp.net

I use InProc mode to store session (sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="240"), I know sometimes the session will lost in InProc mode,what will be happened when the session lost during accessing a webpage? 

Thanks!

Comment: in the middle of the render the session can not lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Global asax you can handle a InProc Session end event:

```
void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E) 
{     
    // do something 
}
```

A few reasons an InProc Session will died:

- Your IIS Application Pool has died,
  reset or etc.
- ASP.NET Worker Process
  (Aspnet_wp.exe) is recycled
  unexpectedly, overriding your bin or
  web.config

Answer (score 0):

If an event occurs that causes the Application Pool to be recycled then `InProc` session will be lost. If the application is servicing a request, then I don't believe that the session associated with that request is lost, at least not until the response is served anyway.